# Java servlet - How to excecute a jar files inside java servlet

Tags: eclipse, servlets, executable-jar, tomcat8

I want to create a platform (PlatA) which is a java servlet web app using apache tomcat. PlatA allows you to upload and extract jar/war files (which are also java servlet webapp) and save this to a directory. My question is now after I extract the jar/war file how do I add a link to Plat(A) to excecute the extracted jar/war file

Comment: What is this application doing? What do you want to achieve by running it from a servlet? Usually, you don't run a Java app from a servlet. You use classes and methods that are in a jar file.

Comment: So I am creating a platform using a servlet and tomcat. This platform allows the user through a web form to upload and unpack Jar files. After unpacking it, I then want to be able to execute the file that has been uploaded.

Comment: Do you realize that 1. a jar file usually has dependencies, and won't run without these dependencies; 2. this is a huge security risk: the jar file you execute could very well just delete all the files on the server, or send them somewhere else, or bring your server to its knees, if you don't have very, very serious sandbox?

Comment: I understand the security risks but this is just a project for me to learn from and wont be used by anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Use  java.lang.[**ProcessBuilder**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

> This class is used to create operating system processes.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "absolute/path/of/jar");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. With this code, is it necessary to unpack the contents of the JAR file ?

Comment: @qwertyayyy even without reading the javadoc, what do you think this code does? If in doubt, read the javadoc. Then, what do you conclude? Do you unpack your jar before executing java -jar NameofJarFile.jar? Then why do you think you should do it here?

Comment: Thank you, I am still a beginner to all this. But thanks for the tip.